# R Convert double to string r without converting to scientific

Tags: r, string, type-conversion, double, tidyverse

Have a scenario where I have a lengthy (12 digit) index value being read into r as a double. I need to concact this with some other identifiers, but `mutate(x = as.character(x))` converts to scientific format:

```
index <- c(123000789000, 123456000000, 123000000012)
concact_val <- c("C", "A", "B")

df <- 
  bind_cols(
    as_tibble(index),
    as_tibble(concact_val)
  )

df %>%
  mutate(index = as.character(index))
```

This outputs:

```
index   concact_val
1.23e11 C
1.23e11 A
1.23e11 B
```

Whereas ideally I'd like to be able to do this:

```
df %>%
  mutate(index = as.character(index),
         index = paste0(concact_val, index)) %>%
  select(-concact_val)
```

to output:

```
index
C123000789000
A123456000000
B123000000012
```

Is there a way around this? In this example, I created a vector for the index, but in the frame I'm reading in it's being read as a double via an API (unfortunately, I can't change the col type prior to reading in, it's being read differently than `read_csv`).

Comment: You can use `options(scipen = 999)` or make convert the integer with `gmp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sprintf`:

```r
df %>%
  mutate(result = sprintf("%s%0.0f", concact_val, index))
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#          index concact_val result       
#          <dbl> <chr>       <chr>        
# 1 123000789000 C           C123000789000
# 2 123456000000 A           A123456000000
# 3 123000000012 B           B123000000012
```

If there is the chance that some `index` have fractional components, this will round them silently. If that's a concern (and you don't want to round), you can instead use `floor(index)` inside the `sprintf`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `sprintf` and `gmp` solutions, we may try another option like below as a programming practice

```
f <- function(x) {
  res <- c()
  while (x) {
    res <- append(res, x %% 10)
    x <- x %/% 10
  }
  paste0(rev(res), collapse = "")
}
paste0(concact_val, Vectorize(f)(index))
# [1] "C123000789000" "A123456000000" "B123000000012"
```

Answer (score 0):

We may use `as.bigz` from `gmp`

```
paste0(concact_val, gmp::as.bigz(index))
[1] "C123000789000" "A123456000000" "B123000000012"
```

Or another option is to specify the `scipen` in `options` to avoid converting to scientific format

```
options(scipen = 999)
```